# Start apps minimized on try for Windows 8.1 startup

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

Is there any way to start a selected app minimized on try on a Windwos 8.1 startup?

I tried with no success with Task Schedule on Windows 8.1 and starting a cmd with the following optional arguments: /c start "ZimMini" /min "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zim Desktop Wiki\zim.exe"

Any ideas?

Comment: You should check the event log for messages that would indicate why your task did not start.

Answer (score 0):

Make a **shortcut** of the Application you want to start minimized.
Put it in the **start-up menu** so it can start at windows load. 
Click **properties** on it. 
Click on the drop-down menu under **Run**. Select "**Minimized**," then click the **OK** button. 
When start of the program occurs, it'll start up minimized. If the program has been written to minimize to the notification area in the system tray it'll show up there, which is even better.

Comment: Not working on Windows 8.1 for Zim app